# Calling a variable declared as a string inside a do while structure outside it

Tags: c#, variables

I am working on an assignment to develop a simple airline booking software using C#. I used a do while statement to collect personal and flight details, my problem now is the variables like full name,  email and phone number.

Now I'm trying to use them as parameters for a method I created to generate flight tickets which will include the full name and the rest, but it's telling me that it can't be used in that context.

```
public void Ticket(string a, string b, string c)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

    Console.WriteLine(a);
    Console.WriteLine(b);
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program Object = new Program();
    do
    {
        // ...
    } 
    while ();
    Object.Ticket(FullName, Arrival_City, Depart_City);
}
```

Comment: Please post your code so that we have something to review. What you're describing sounds like a syntax error but without seeing your code we can not help you determine what the incorrect syntax is.

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, how can we even begin to help you?

Comment: Alright, will do that in a sec, using a mobile to post this right now, will use a pc to that right away

Comment: THAT IS THE CODE FRAGMENT FOR THE METHOD I CREATED TO DISPLAY THE FULLNAME, DEPARTURE CITY AND ARRIVAL CITY, PLUS DATE OF BOOKING.

Comment: ^ Binbello, please delete code from the comments and add it to the question using the [edit feature](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35705200/edit). There is a code formatting button - select the code and click. It's also a good idea to avoid shouty all-caps around here, it's a good way to get downvoted.

Comment: THAT IS HOW AM TRYING TO CALL THE METHOD TO DISPLAY THOSE INFO IN THE BRACKET, BUT ITS COMPLAINING OF THAT THE VARIABLES CAN NOT BE USED IN THIS CONTEXT, Remember, I Declared the variables above inside a do while statement

Comment: Well, from the site rules: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. And stop screaming.

Comment: Edit feature not working from my PC, don't know why

Comment: If you declare something inside a do-while-structure, it's only accessible inside. Declare your variables before the while-loop to access them after the loop. And read an article or two about scope :-)

Comment: Declared it outside, but it keeps complaining of it not being initialized.. These variables are of string type.

Comment: See my answer below, you're not allowed to use uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to declare (and initialize) the variables outside the while loop:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program Object = new Program();
    var FullName = string.Empty;
    var Arrival_City = string.Empty;
    var Depart_City = string.Empty;
    do
    {
        // ...
    } 
    while ();
    Object.Ticket(FullName, Arrival_City, Depart_City);
}
```

You can, of course, be more verbose and use `string` to declare them, as in

```
string FullName = string.Empty; // or "" if you prefer. or even null here.
```

Variables are only visible inside the scope they're created in (between `{` and `}`)...

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue. Thanks

Comment: Why downvote? Any room for improvement I'm missing out?

Answer (score -1):

1)Your second method has to be static

```
public static void Ticket(string a, string b, string c)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

    Console.WriteLine(a);
    Console.WriteLine(b);
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    do
    {
        // ...
    } 
    while ();
    Ticket(FullName, Arrival_City, Depart_City);
}
```

2)Or you should not use class name Object as variable name.

Comment: Tried changing the other method to static, but didn't work, I still can't use those variables as the parameters for the other method